# Add unique constraint to date portion of a DateTime column

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

In MySQL is it possible to do a unique constraint for the date portion of a `dateTime` column?

For example if I had `2018-10-01 10:05:06`, the following would not be allowed `2018-10-01 11:00:00`, because it has the same date.

Currently my best solution is to separate the dateTime column in to a separate date and time column, and perform a unique operation on the date column.

Comment: You may create a calculated field to contain the Date and then create a UNIQUE constraint in this new field.

Answer (score 1):

This is too complex to be natively handled by MySQL, that has a quite limited support for constraints anyway.

You would have to create :

- a stored procedure that performs the check
- `BEFORE` triggers for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, that call the procedure

Here is what the procedure should look like (assuming that the table is named `my_table` and that the column holding the datetime is `my_datetime`) :

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE `check_new_datetime`(IN new_datetime DATETIME)
BEGIN
    IF new_datetime IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE DATE(new_datetime) = DATE(my_datetime)) > 0 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint check_new_datetime failed';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Triggers creation :

```
-- before insert
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `my_table_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL check_new_datetime(new.my_datetime);
END$$   
DELIMITER ; 

-- before update
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `my_table_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL check_new_datetime(new.my_datetime);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't but as a work-around

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_x (
  ts DateTime,
  gents Date AS (CAST(tbl_x.ts AS DATE)),
  UNIQUE(gents)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You understand one method, which is to split the date and time into separate columns.  That is probably the simplest method.

A trigger is another method, but that is rather painful to maintain.

Another possibility is to use column prefixes.  The downside is that the column needs to be stored as a string:

```
create table t (
    . . .,
    datetimecol char(19),  -- format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS"
);

create unique index unq_t_datetimecol on t(datetimecol(10));
```

This approach is so useful that MySQL has finally implemented indexes using expressions in 8.0.13.  This allows:

```
create table t (
    . . .,
    datetimecol datetime, 
    . . .
);

create unique index unq_t_datetimecol on t(date(datetimecol));
```

Oh, there is another method using generated columns as well:

```
create table t (
    . . .,
    datetimecol datetime, 
    . . .,
    datecol date generated always as (date(datetimecol)) stored,
    unique (datecol)
);
```